# UART STM32 not working correctly when trying a mirror/echo test

Tags: c, stm32, interrupt, uart, nucleo

I am trying to create a mirror/echo test using powerline and stm32 through UART (nucleo F401RE). With this project I'm relearning C as I haven't coded in a while.

I have to boards, a Master board and a slave one. The master generates a string that is sent through a power line module: ie.. Sending string %d. The slave receives the string, and replies with a string saying... I have received %d value.This with the end of checking tha the value sent is the same on the slave.

**UPDATE:**
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClA9d.png)

Let me explain better, I am sending the following string:

3C980100003DC100000000003200000000000032A3BA0049534901015C543035375C58315C46305C44315C43325C5039365C4D31315C4A3030436F67616E3230303030C4DC363E

In ascii as shown in the Console image it is delimited by the symbols <>. The number after Cogan is incremented and I want to extract that value. I have manage to do this, however, I have found some data loss. I used UART in polling mode, I have had to find that my Receive timeout has to be half the time I am sending the data, i.e. I send every 2 s and my receive timeout is 1 sec. In the example of the image, I send the string with the number 27, my slave receives and replies I received number 27. The next number starts in master, I send number 28, slave receives number 28 and replies I received number 28. However, master does not detect this message but it has been sent because I can see it with a sniffer on my powerline.
Hope this diagram helps a bit.

**Master (Transmitter receiver)**            || Transmit -> Receive | Transmit -> Receive | Transmit -> Receive

**Slave (Receive transmitter)** || Receive -> Transmit | Receive -> Transmit | Receive -> Transmit

I'm trying now with Interrupts, constantly sending message and trying to receive with HAL_UART_Receive_IT, trying using the callback however, first I had the 8 error code (overrun error). Now, I don't see the error while debugging but it seems my callbakc is just working once.

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {

if(huart->Instance == USART1){ /* Do everything in this block */
    
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, RxData, sizeof(RxData));
    sprintf(msgOut, "\r\n String \r\n  ");
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)msgOut, strlen(msgOut), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    // Iterate through the array and print each element
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(RxData); i++) {
        sprintf(msgOut, "%02X ", RxData[i]);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)msgOut, strlen(msgOut), HAL_MAX_DELAY);// %02X formats the number as a two-digit hexadecimal
        }
     sprintf(msgStatus, "\r\n  ");
     HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)msgStatus, strlen(msgStatus), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
     

} else {/* Do nothing */

}
```

I receive the following and then stops. I don't have the continuous messages stream that is coming:

3C 98 01 10 00 38 1F FF 00 FE 18 F2 00 30 32 A3 BA 00 49 53 49 01 01 5C 54 30 35 37 5C 58 31 5C 46 30 5C 44 31 5C 43 32 5C 50 39 36 5C 4D 31 31 5C 4A 30 30 43 6F 67 61 6E 32 30 30 91 E9 8E 3E
3C 98 01 10 00 38 1F FF 00 FE 18 F2 00 30 32 A3 BA 00 49 53 49 01 01 5C 54 30 35 37 5C 58 31 5C 46 30 5C 44 31 5C 43 32 5C 50 39 36 5C 4D 31 31 5C 4A 30 30 43 6F 67 61 6E 32 30 30 91 E9 8E 3E
3C 98 01 10 00 38 1F FF 00 FE 18 F2 00 30 32 A3 BA 00 49 53 49 01 01 5C 54 30 35 37 5C 58 31 5C 46 30 5C 44 31 5C 43 32 5C 50 39 36 5C 4D 31 31 5C 4A 30 30 43 6F 67 61 6E 32 30 30 91 E9 8E 3E
3C 98 01 10 00 38 1F FF 00 FE 18 F2 00 30 32 A3 BA 00 49 53 49 01 01 5C 54 30 35 37 5C 58 31 5C 46 30 5C 44 31 5C 43 32 5C 50 39 36 5C 4D 31 31 5C 4A 30 30 43 6F 67 61 6E 32 30 30 91 E9 8E 3E

Comment: You didn't show us any of your code, so who can tell.

Comment: Apologies, I was working on some other things I just had access to my computer now.

Comment: Please, simplify your program for debugging. Use very short messages of a couple characters, see how it reacts to that. It's really hard to compare various gibberish strings you posted. Please, use either only printable characters for debugging, or use raw HEX codes, so they're comparable at first sight. You're making things harder to debug for yourself and harder to understand for others.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm adjusting the code for this. You're right.. it  will be better with hex codes, however the issue is not with the printable characters or the content of the string, it is on how transmission is made. I'll be adjusting as requested, the delimiters that I use are <> which on hex are 0x3C and 0x3E.

Comment: It's about how easy it is to read. Right now I need a magnifying glass and 20 minutes of reading non-printable characters to (maybe) actually understand what you're sending where and how it goes wrong. If you just send "0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34" and you receive "0x31 0x32 0x33", you can see immediately where the problem is. Simplify your program to the most basic form where you still have that issue.

Comment: yes, ok. Agreed. I'll be updating those things in the post in the next few hours. Thanks!

Comment: Have updated my question, many thanks for all your support.